# Retrieve rows from spreadsheet data using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I am using Google app script to write form data to spreadsheet. Now I would like to fetch the values from Excel which matches conditions (eg., filtered by date, username) and display them with app script.

My spreadsheet has

```
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+
| Date        | Username  | Comment              |
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+
| 2012-05-02  | palani    | My first comment     |
| 2012-05-02  | raja      | My second comment    |
| 2012-05-03  | palani    | My third comment     |
| 2012-05-03  | raja      | My fourth comment    |
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

Now I want to filter data for `2012-05-02` on date and `raja` on username and display them using labels in app-script (which is running as a web service).

All my searches return solution using [`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#getDataRange) which i think is not optimized way to display one record out of 1000+ rows in sheet.

**EDIT**

Right now, I am using `.getValues()` only. And the data shown here is for sample; my real sheet has 15 column and 5000+ rows for now. And eventually it will grow to millions as this is a timesheet application. I am wondering is there any other way to `getValues()` of filtered rows?

Applying `=Filter` formula on a tmp cell will also be an issue, as script could be used simultaneously by number of people.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to getValues with applied filter. But if your data grow to millions of rows, the script will not be your primary concern, as a spreadsheet can only hold 400 thousand cells.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The easiest way, and the one I know, is to :
get the values in an Array using

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
```

then to make a loop

```
for (i in data) {
```

in this loop to check if the date (`data[i][0]`) is equal to the one you're looking for, and if the name (`data[i][1]`) is equal to the one you're looking for too. And push it to an array

```
var labels=new Array;
label.push( [data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2]] );
```

then having all your data in this array, you can populate a panen Ui with label using a for loop

```
for (i in labels) { ...
```

Comment: thanks @cartman. But I have thousands of records and looping it seems to be bad solution.

Comment: Thousands of rows is definitely very few, specially with 3 columns only. Getting all at once with getValues and looping is the solution here. Unless there's something we do not know about your data or usage. e.g. the filter is static, or the data is.

Comment: You may need to use `getDisplayValues` instead of `getValues` if your spreadsheet contains Date fields, as `getValues` fails by default when your rows contain Date fields

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can consider use a cell and use the "Query" formula on it. Lets assume Date is at Column A, Username = Column B, Comment is Column C, while the blank cell is D1, your script will look like this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D1").setFormula('Query(A:C,"SELECT A,B,C WHERE B="' + "SomeOne'" + ',1)'; //filter the data and populate to D1 onwards    
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D:F").getValues();//this is the filtered data
```