# How do I pass a value from an HTML form submission to a Google Sheet and back to HTML in a Google Apps Script Web App

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-apps-script, google-apps-for-education

I'm trying to create a basic time clock web app.

So far, I'm using [this script](https://script.google.com/d/1dpWeM8pMyqxZQQKvkchc6t4p07hAlVHs4q41bkunjVxj-cvPht_B88i6/edit?usp=sharing) to create [this web app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyiVWtwqEijFc8n93AWp07NVMKXl4y58MM9d3KU8meF7PhE6MS4/exec) which takes the input values and puts them in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GYGpzY7--e-8-pMMD0L_HyXXZO4GGPzAndt5MHxplmg/edit?usp=sharing) for the time stamping part.

I need it to use one of the values from the form and perform a lookup [in this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GYGpzY7--e-8-pMMD0L_HyXXZO4GGPzAndt5MHxplmg/edit#gid=1224249960) (take the longId and find me the name) and return the (name) value to the html page as a verification for the end user that they were identified correctly. Unfortunately, I don't know enough to grasp what I'm doing wrong. Let me know if I need to provide more info.

**Edit 1**

I'm thinking that I wasn't clear enough. I don't need the user info from entry, I need the user from a lookup. The user will be entering their ID anonymously, I need to match the ID to their info, and bring the info back for them to verify.

**Edit 2**

Using the link provided by Br. Sayan, I've created [this script](https://script.google.com/d/1y78LARlhDQQ27hQSDugIQc9ongBmQ6_XpLZCdNPcr3gssx-AInsI6wRT/edit?usp=sharing) using [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15DRZRQ2Hcd7MNnAsu_lnZ6n4kiHeXW_OMPP3squbTLE/edit#gid=0) as above to test one piece of this. [The web app here](https://script.google.com/a/macros/fjuhsd.org/s/AKfycbyIoBmPZntLn0W3cMmIlsSJDFkDsN9r958fEzeM8yo/exec) spits out: undefined. It should spit out "Student 3" Still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Oops. That's still left over from testing. Deleted. It should trigger with the form "submit" input labeled "Next...". You should be able to see it in the Javascript.html file.

Comment: You can do away with outer `[  ]` in `student.push([data[i][0]]);` I suppose. Shouldn't it be `student.push(data[i][0]);` And also please let's know what does, `Logger.log(data[i][0])` say? Put it right after `Logger.log("yes")`. Otherwise we need to use the `console.log()` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one:

[image: Fetch Data from Google Spread Sheet]
<sub>(source: [technokarak.com](http://technokarak.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Code-to-Fetch-Data-from-Google-SpreadSheet1.png))</sub>

Also please have a look at:

[Retrieve rows from spreadsheet data using GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518084/retrieve-rows-from-spreadsheet-data-using-google-app-script)

**EDIT:**

Please make these changes in your function and let us know.

```
function findValue() {
  var data =        SpreadsheetApp.openById("15DRZRQ2Hcd7MNnAsu_lnZ6n4kiHeXW_OMPP3squbTLE").getSheetByName("Volatile Data").getDataRange().getValues();
  for(i in data) {
    if(data[i][3] == 100000003) {
      Logger.log("yes");
      Logger.log(data[i][0]);
      var student = [];
      student.push(data[i][0]);
      return student;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do away with outer `[ ]` in `student.push([data[i][0]]);`I suppose. Shouldn't it be `student.push(data[i][0]);` And also please let's know what does, `Logger.log(data[i][0])` say? Put it after `Logger.log("yes")`. Otherwise we need to use the `console.log()` to see what's going on.

Comment: I've edited the function a little in my answer itself. Please try and let me know.

Comment: As Bryan P has mentioned , you run the `google.script.run` with the event i.e mouseClick or whatsoever and in the function in `Code.gs` simply do a `return student`, which you already have. Only replace the `.findStudent(value);` with `.findValue(SpreadsheetId)`. Now your `Index.html` and `Code.gs` are not matching. `value` - which you're passing to the function contains nothing as such. Please check and make the changes and let me know. :)

Comment: See question edit. Unfortunately now all IDs are returning as "Student 1". I added a few console logs in an attempt to help.

Comment: Don't need console.log(). Post the Logger.log() entries please.

Comment: Also add a `Logger.log('i : ' + i);` to get the value for `i` also, before `Logger.log("Match Found");`

Comment: Found the problem - I had ===, needed ==. All looks good for now. Will do some more testing and update.

Answer (score 1):

One way for the next button to grab the student input field:

`<input type="submit" onclick="studentName(document.getElementById('student').value)" value="Next..."/>`

That sends the value to this func in **Javascript.html**:

```
function studentName(value) {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(findSuccess)
  .findStudent(value);
}
```

Which sends it to a `findStudent(value)` in **Code.gs**
You do the lookup and the return value goes back to `findSuccess( result )` back in **Javascript.html**. Handle the `result` from there.

Also consider keeping  the stock `preventDefault()` code that comes with the Web App template in the Help > Welcome Screen.

Comment: I'm going to look into this one thank you! And - whoa on the Web App template. I've never used that. That is a lot of info to take in! That will take me a minute to wrap my head around. Thank you!

Comment: This is a huge help, and I think that I've nearly gotten it, but I'm still doing something wrong. See update in original post.

Comment: Sorry, I just figured context would be a good thing. I don't really know what I'm looking for, so I don't really know what someone who does, like you guys, would need to see. I'll attempt to simplify in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is a complicated answer, I have had a lot of success with:

```
function process(object){

  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var key = object.Key;

  send(key);

}

function send(k){

  var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastR = ss.GetLastRow();

  ss.GetRange(lastR,1).SetValue(k);

}
```

On your html button you will need to have inside the tags

```
onClick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(Success)
          .process(this.parentNode);"
```

In order for this to work, obviously you will need to have your fields named accordingly.

Edit: The only thing I did not include in the code was a Success handler, which will be in your html of the GAS script. [This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) should point you in a direction that can resolve that.

Hope this helps.