# Get data from row into an array

Tags: google-apps-script

a really quick question... I want to read rows in sheets one by one, (preferably 'live' so rather than putting it in an array or something). Besides using a loop, how do I read the contents of a whole row? Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve rows from spreadsheet data using google app script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518084/retrieve-rows-from-spreadsheet-data-using-google-app-script)

Comment: You might consider setting up a separate sheet that will filter the row you are interested in instead of using Google Apps scripts.

Answer (score 9):

You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

```
function readData() {
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = sht.getRange(rownumber, 1, 1, numberofcolums)
  var rangeArray = rng.getValues();
//now all your data for that row is in a two Dimensional array [[1,2,3,4,'My Data','etc']]  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var
  spreadsheetID =
    "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms",
  rowNum = 1,
  rowVals =
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID)
    .getRange(rowNum +":"+ rowNum)
    .getValues()
;
```

The other answers to date don't get a row, they get a range of specfic columns within a row. The code in this answer gets the entire unbounded row.

Comment: This still seems to be returning an array within an array, no? I did sheet.getRange('1:1').getValues() and I had to access the inner array with [0].

Comment: Rivers Cuomo: The Range is always a 2D array of row arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your end goal is, but I assume you mean something like this:

```
      var values = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols).getValues(); // returns 2d array

      values.forEach(function(row){

             Logger.log(row); // prints the contents of the row

          });
```

You could also use the getCell() method of the Range class to iterate over cells in a range. The return type for getCell() is also Range. See this thread for details on the implementation [Google Spreadsheets: Iterate over range, append string to each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605213/google-spreadsheets-iterate-over-range-append-string-to-each)